# Developer Story thinks my work experience is incomplete

Tags: support, developer-story

Trying out the Beta without doing much pre-reading.  I noticed that it complained that "Work experience / education" was incomplete (see screenshot) so I filled it in.  It still thinks it's missing though.  A bug?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I RTFM'ed and see that I didn't fill in "2 technologies" or fill in "150 char for responsibilities".  I was planning to just keep it Title-Only, but I'll put them in to make Dev Story happy.

Comment: Nice to see a happy ending for this Dev Story. :P